# Why are linked components not resizable in GroupLayout?

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

For the GUI of a calculator application I'm making, I have a grid of `JButton` objects, where all of them are the same size, except one is double the width of the others.  It should look something like this (except the lines would be straight):

[image]

My first thought would be that I define a size for the `JButton` objects (let's call it `CELL_SIZE`), and then set the preferred size of the buttons to `CELL_SIZE`,  except the longer button would have `CELL_SIZE * 2`.  This works until you resize the window.  I want the buttons to resize themselves so that whatever the dimensions of the window are, all the buttons are the same size, except the longer one.  So I tried using `linkSize`, with all the buttons except the long one as the arguments.  But the buttons wouldn't resize!  I then read in the javadoc that `linkSize` prevents components from being resized.  Why is this?  Can I use this method to accomplish this layout, or do I need something else?

Below is a class I typed up to demonstrate the problem (the actual application is crowded with other functionality besides the layout)  It only has 5 buttons, and serves to represent the bottom-left 3x2 area of the image.

```
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class A extends JPanel{

    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 32;
    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("5");

    public A(){
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(b1, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(b2, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            ).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(b3, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(b4, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                )
                .addComponent(b5, 0, CELL_SIZE * 2, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            )
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(b1, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(b3, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(b4, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            ).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(b2, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(b5, 0, CELL_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            )
        );
        layout.linkSize(b1, b2, b3, b4);
        setLayout(layout);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GroupLayout Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new A());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

EDIT: If I call `addComponent(component, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)` and remove the `linkSize` call, then the buttons sizes get strange.  `b1` and `b2` become wider than `b3` and `b4`, but not as wide as `b5`.

Comment: GridBagLayout might be a better option here, it has built-in support for grid-based layout, including elements spanning multiple cells like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html):

1) To force a component to be resizable (allow shrinking and growing):

```
group.addComponent(component, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE) ...
```

This allows the component to resize between zero size (minimum) to any size (Short.MAX_VALUE as maximum size means "infinite"). If we wanted the component not to shrink below its default minimum size, we would use GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE instead of 0 in the second parameter.

2) To make a component fixed size (suppress resizing):

```
group.addComponent(component, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
          GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE) ...
```

I think you should use 1st option.

Comment: If I do that, then the components don't resize properly.  `b1` and `b2` are made wider than `b3` and `b4`, but not as wide as `b5`.